# How do I fill a column with values when those values are displayed in other columns in R?

Tags: r

I'm performing a conjoint analysis and now I'm preparing the dataset, so it is appropriate for model building. I have 1 column that identifies the ID of the respondent, one column that represents the choiceset (`Set_id`), one column that identifies the alternatives (`Alternative_id`) from each choiceset, and I have one column that should represent the actual choice (`Selection`). The survey consists of 12 choice-sets, so for one person, there are 48 rows with variables.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqzDX.png)

My question is about the column `Selection`. I want to fill the column `Selection` with peoples choices, however, the output of the survey has a different format (see picture).

[Choices respondents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnO42.png)

So, for `Set_id == 1`, I want R to fill the values that are represented in column `Choiceset.1`, for `Set_id == 2`, I want R to fill the values that are represented in column `Choiceset.2` etc., and this for every respondent.

I tried to do it like this:

```
cbc$Selection[(cbc$Set_id == 1)] <- cbc$Choiceset.1
cbc$Selection[(cbc$Set_id == 2)] <- cbc$Choiceset.2
```

etc.

R fills the column with values, but they are the same for every respondent. R only picks the upper four values, the choices made by `ID = 1`. So the values are only right for `ID = 1`, but are wrong from `ID = 2` and further, because R only picks the upper four values from the columns.

I hope this is a clear explanation about the problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the code below might solve the problem. Untested, since the data was posted as an image, not in copy&paste able format.

```
for(i in unique(cbc$Set_id)){
  j <- which(cbc$Set_id == i)
  choice_col <- paste("Choiceset", i, sep = ".")
  cbc$Selection[j] <- cbc[j, choice_col]
}
```